# jQuery: Passing argument (results) between event listeners

Tags: jquery

Please see bottom code.

```
$('.some-selector').mousedown(function(evn1){
  $('body').mousemove(function(evn2){
    // how to access env1?
  });
});
```

Can somebody please explain this to me?

I am also interested how is this working on JavaScript level. As far as I my knowledge goes: I am calling method mousedown on some-selector object by passing function. I am kinda confused why I am stating env1 here, this should be result.

Comment: You can access `evn1` normally... It will be captured in the closure of `mousemove`'s callback function... Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: You should almost never define one event handler inside another. Every time you click on `.some-selector`, it will add an additional `.mousemove()` handler on the body.

Comment: Define both handlers at top-level, and use a global variable to pass values between them.

Comment: Using the shown code here will cause severe performance and logical error issues on the page.

Comment: not sure why everyone excited about adding mousemove handler inside mousedown...is very common for moving elements. Important to remove it on mouseup though. The 2 arguments are the event objects. Not clear what goal is here though

Comment: @Andre it is not defined if I output it instead of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access evn1 normally... It will be captured in the closure of mousemove's callback function...

Are you sure you haven't mistyped `evn1` as `env1`?

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andreortigao/kh1gLzbr/

Comment: This is correct, my bad. Thank you @andre for the effort.